Raster upside down in QGIS
I have raster which, when opening on QGIS, the map turns out to be upside down. 
I tried fixing the data gdal_translate -of netCDF -co WRITE_BOTTOMUP=NO meancount_25.nc meancount_25_fixed.nc. Is there something wrong with my code?
Here's the `gdalinfo`
Driver: netCDF/Network Common Data Format
Files: meancount_25.nc
       meancount_25.nc.aux.xml
Size is 1440, 721
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["latitude",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["longitude",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (0.000000000000000,0.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (1.000000000000000,-1.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  Band1#grid_mapping=crs
  Band1#long_name=GDAL Band Number 1
  Band1#_FillValue=nan
  crs#GeoTransform=0 1 0 0 0 -1 
  crs#grid_mapping_name=latitude_longitude
  crs#inverse_flattening=298.257223563
  crs#longitude_of_prime_meridian=0
  crs#long_name=CRS definition
  crs#semi_major_axis=6378137
  crs#spatial_ref=GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],AXIS["Longitude",EAST],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
  lat#long_name=latitude
  lat#standard_name=latitude
  lat#units=degrees_north
  lon#long_name=longitude
  lon#standard_name=longitude
  lon#units=degrees_east
  NC_GLOBAL#Conventions=CF-1.5
  NC_GLOBAL#GDAL=GDAL 3.3.2, released 2021/09/01
  NC_GLOBAL#history=Thu Jun 27 19:44:40 2024: GDAL Create( /Users/pulaharoy/Downloads/meancount_25.nc, ... )
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Lower Left  (       0.000,    -721.000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,Invalid angle)
Upper Right (    1440.000,       0.000) (Invalid angle,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Lower Right (    1440.000,    -721.000) (Invalid angle,Invalid angle)
Center      (     720.000,    -360.500) (Invalid angle,360d30' 0.00"S)
Band 1 Block=1440x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Min=-0.500 Max=88.833 
  Minimum=-0.500, Maximum=88.833, Mean=3.971, StdDev=10.743
  NoData Value=nan
  Metadata:
    grid_mapping=crs
    long_name=GDAL Band Number 1
    NETCDF_VARNAME=Band1
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=88.833333333333
    STATISTICS_MEAN=3.9710071639275
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=-0.5
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=10.743173012789
    _FillValue=nan


Try to change the reading side, not writing. gdal_translate -of netCDF  meancount_25.nc meancount_25_fixed.nc --config GDAL_NETCDF_BOTTOMUP YES. I do not know if it should be YES or NO, or if it will have any effect.
